# How do I get the index of object in array using angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, indexof

I need to have the index of an object in array so I can delete this part of the array. I tried using this:

```
var index = this.urenRegistratie.indexOf(newDatum);
```

But it keeps returning -1 and I don't know why this is happening.

this is the part of the code I have. it gets data out of a form in html and places that into my array, now I already have an if statement ready  ( exisitingDatum )  , my code needs to be in there. Can someone please help me out a bit?

```
 store(newValue:number, newDatum, newAanwezig, newComment){
    const existingDatum = this.urenRegistratie.find(billable => {
      return billable.datum === newDatum;
      return
    });

    if (!existingDatum) {
        let billable = new BillableHours();
        billable.datum = newDatum;
        billable.hours = +newValue;
        billable.aanwezig = newAanwezig;
        billable.comment = newComment;

        if(billable.aanwezig == "Aanwezig" && billable.hours !== 0 && billable.datum !== null) {
          this.urenRegistratie.push(billable);
        }
    }

    if(existingDatum) {

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

> The findIndex() method returns the index of **the first element** in the
> array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, it
> returns -1, indicating that no element passed the test.

If you have array of objects like this, then try to use `findIndex`:

```js
const a = [
    { firstName: "Adam", LastName: "Howard" },
    { firstName: "Ben", LastName: "Skeet" },
    { firstName: "Joseph", LastName: "Skeet" }
];

const index = a.findIndex(x => x.LastName === "Skeet");
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the answer of @StepUp (and please select his answer as best, as it replies the question greatly):

Finding the index is not related to Angular, it is rather Vanilla JavaScript.

In your case, you need a function that has as parameter the `newDatum` "needle" to be searched in the array "haystack" using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
var getNewDatumIndex = (array, newDatumNeedle) => {
  return array.findIndex(x => x.newDatum === newDatumNeedle); 
}
```

You can also add the method in the array prototype if you want, in order to ommit the first argument:

```
Array.prototype.getNewDatumIndex = (newDatumNeedle) => {
  return this.findIndex(x => x.newDatum === newDatumNeedle); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> An easy and elegant solution is to use [_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual), which performs a deep comparison using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) library
>
> Npm Package -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash

```
const a = [
   { firstName: "Adam", LastName: "Howard" },
   { firstName: "Ben", LastName: "Skeet" },
   { firstName: "Joseph", LastName: "Skeet" }
];
const find =  { firstName: "Joseph", LastName: "Skeet" }

index = a.findIndex(x => _.isEqual(x, find));

console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

store(newValue: number, newDatum, newAanwezig, newComment) {
let index = this.urenRegistratie.indexOf(existingDatum);

```
const existingDatum = this.urenRegistratie.find(billable => {
  return billable.datum === newDatum;
  return
});

if (index != -1) {
  let index = this.urenRegistratie.indexOf(existingDatum);
  existingDatum.splice(index, 1)
} else {

  let billable = new BillableHours();
  billable.datum = newDatum;
  billable.hours = +newValue;
  billable.aanwezig = newAanwezig;
  billable.comment = newComment;

  if (billable.aanwezig == "Aanwezig" && billable.hours !== 0 && billable.datum !== null) {
    this.urenRegistratie.push(billable);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

sometimes, if you compare by id, you need to parseint, cause object's id is a string. care of this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).